# Where can I find a syntax reference for Oracle SQL Developer's "Generate DB Doc" function?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, plsql, oracle-sql-developer, documentation

Oracle SQL Developer (I'm using v3.2) has a feature called "DB Doc", which generates documentation for database objects. I mostly want to use it to generate documentation for my stored procedures, functions, packages and types. However, I can't find any documentation for it, describing what syntax I should use.

I have worked out that I should use a `/* ... */` comment on the line(s) immediately above my procedure/whatever, and (by borrowing from JavaDoc) I have successfully used `@param` and `@returns` statements, but I'm not sure what else I can use. For example, are there fields for author, version, data modified, etc.?

I've done numerous searches of this site, Google, and Oracle's documentation, to no avail!

Comment: Here is some information from Oracle Guru Jeff Smith. https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/03/javadoc-for-the-database-a-la-dbdoc-via-sql-developer/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) initially based on comments left by [thatjeffsmith](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/271/thatjeffsmith):</sub>*

This is an exhaustive list of what it supports:

(reproduced from http://pldoc.sourceforge.net/maven-site/samples/sample1.sql)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE CUSTOMER_DATA
IS
/** 
* Project:         Test Project (<a href="http://pldoc.sourceforge.net">PLDoc</a>)<br/>
* Description:     Customer Data Management<br/>
* DB impact:       YES<br/>
* Commit inside:   NO<br/>
* Rollback inside: NO<br/>
* @headcom
*/

/**
* Record of customer data.
*
* @param id     customer ID
* @param name       customer name
* @param regno      registration number or SSN
* @param language   preferred language
*/
TYPE customer_type IS RECORD (
  id                        VARCHAR2(20),
  name                      VARCHAR2(100),
  regno                     VARCHAR2(50),
  language                  VARCHAR2(10)
);

/** Table of customer records. */
TYPE customer_table IS TABLE OF customer_type INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

/**
* Gets customer by ID.
*
* @param p_id       customer ID
* @param r          record of customer data
* @throws no_data_found if no such customer exists
*/
PROCEDURE get_customer (
  p_id              VARCHAR2,
  customer_rec      OUT customer_type);

/**
* Searches customer by criteria.
*
* @param p_criteria record with assigned search criteria
* @param r_records  table of found customers <b>(may be empty!)</b>
*/
PROCEDURE get_by_criteria (
  p_criteria        customer_type,
  r_records         OUT customer_table);

/**
* Creates a customer record.
*
* @param customer_rec record of customer data
*/
PROCEDURE create_customer (
  customer_rec      customer_type);

/**
* Changes customer data.
*
* @param customer_rec record of updated customer data
*/
PROCEDURE update_customer (
  customer_rec      customer_type);

END;
/
```

We support everything in PLDOC - we just have a GUI vs a CLI for it. There are three code samples there, you should be able to do anything listed in those samples.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to use [PLDOC](http://pldoc.sourceforge.net/maven-site/index.html) for PLSQL Documentation generation.
It's similar to JavaDoc (slightly limited functionality, but has basics like @return, @throw, @param and etc.).

Comment: I agree, but this isn't really an answer to my question - @thatjeffsmith did that in a comment above.